# Addinf a clone copy of the checked items in a listview to new one along with other textbox data / C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to add a clone copy of all checked items in a listviewOne to listviewTwo.
along with other text box values to the listviewTwo. But I am getting error .. Please someone help me..

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                if (item.Checked)
                {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox1.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox2.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox3.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox4.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(item.Text);
        listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
        }
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection.Add(System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)' has some invalid arguments G:\Advanced Programing D201\Assignment 40\StudentLinkModified2\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 164 13 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem' G:\Advanced Programing D201\Assignment 40\StudentLinkModified2\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 164 31 WindowsFormsApplication1

Answer (score 0):

This line has the error:

```
lvi.SubItems.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
```

You can't add a `ListViewItem` to the SubItems collection. You can either add a `ListViewSubItem` or add a string (which creates a new item with that string).

In this case, maybe it's good enough if you create a new sub-item using the text from the checked items in `listView1`. Change the line to:

```
lvi.SubItems.Add(item.Text);
```

---

Ok, so you want all the subItems from listView1 added to the item of listView2. Try this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    if (item.Checked)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox1.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox2.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox3.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(textBox4.Text);
        foreach (ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems)
        {
            lvi.SubItems.Add(subItem);
        }
        listView2.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeh, that is good to get one of the listviewOne item but its not displaying all the checked items. Plus now its not displaying subitems from those textboxes..